# asp.net core image is not displayed in outlook (in browser src is blockedimagesrc)

Tags: c#, css, outlook, smtp, src

I am trying to send an email with a logo image.

But log is not displayed in outlook on browser.
But works on book-mail app (outlook). I can see the image on this application

And works fine in Gmail(both app & browser) too.

In outlook

```
<img blockedimagesrc="/mysite/image/logo.png"/>
```

It shows `blockedimagesrc` instead of `src`

This is my function to send mail

```
public void HandleSendMail(string subject, string body, string to)
        {
            var host = _config.GetSection("Email:HOST").Value;
            var port = _config.GetSection("Email:PORT").Value;
            var username = _config.GetSection("Email:Credentials:Username").Value;
            var password = _config.GetSection("Email:Credentials:Password").Value;
            var toEmail = to;

            using var mm = new MailMessage("noreply@xyz.com", toEmail);
            mm.Subject = subject;
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mm.Body += body;

            using var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = host,
                Port = int.Parse(port),
                EnableSsl = true,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password),
            };

            try
            {
                smtp.Send(mm);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in Creating Message(): {0}",
                    ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Image tag

`<img id="logo"  style="width:100px; height: 100px;" class="logo" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/something-/bfd72a78e706.png?tr=w-200,h-200" alt="whv-logo ">`

Please help me to fix this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had to think really hard, where did I solve this problem you mention. You have to add linked resources to your mail message like this.

```
                AlternateView alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(GetHtmlNotification(), null, "text/html");
                alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(GetLinkedResrouce($"{BaseDirectory}/content/images/logo/{School}/logo.png", "logo"));
                alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(GetLinkedResrouce($"{BaseDirectory}/content/images/logo/wur/W_internet.png", "wlogo"));

                mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(alternateView);


    /// <summary>
    /// Get a Html Notification with header body and footer from a template
    /// </summary>
    private string GetHtmlNotification()
    {
        var fullTemplateName = Path.Combine(BaseDirectory, "EmailTemplates", $"{NotificationTemplateName}.cshtml");
        var template = File.ReadAllText(fullTemplateName);

        Engine.Razor.AddTemplate($"{School}layout", GetLayout());
        var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "key", null, this);
        return result;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Get the school specific layout for the email.
    /// </summary>
    private string GetLayout()
    {
        var fileName = Path.Combine(BaseDirectory, "EmailTemplates", "Layout", $"_{School}Layout.cshtml");
        return File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    }
```

And in our template

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html lang="nl-NL" xml:lang="nl-NL" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="emailTemplateType" content="Your-Organization-NL" />
    <meta name="emailTemplateVersion" content="3.4" />
</head>
<body style="width:100% !important;margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#ececec;font-family:Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#333333;font-size:14px;line-height:18px">
    <body>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="640" style="border:1px solid #d6d6d6;background-color:#ffffff;margin-bottom:20px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:20px">
                                <img src="cid:logo" height="55" style="outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table style="width: 100%; background-color: #34B233; text-align: left;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-left: 8px; color: #FFFFFF;">
                                <h2>@Model.Subject</h2>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 8px;">
                    @Raw(Model.Body)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table height="120px" style="height: 120px; width: 100%; background-color: #34B233; text-align: left;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:20px">
                                <a href="http://www.your.url" style="padding-left: 8px; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left;">
                                    <img title="Your organization" class="left logo" alt="Your organiaztion" src="cid:wlogo" />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
```

The images will be embedded in the email.

Comment: Correct. Outlook doesn't understand base64 encoded images and blocks internet images.

Comment: @Paul Hi, I use a url for src of my image
See `<img id="logo"  style="width:100px; height: 100px;" class="logo" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/something-/bfd72a78e706.png?tr=w-200,h-200" alt="whv-logo "> `
You answer says the path the src, i.e : $"{BaseDirectory}/content/images/logo/{School}/logo.png"

I don't use static images. I have to use a url for src
How can I do that?